# Will garlic cloves that are broken off the root 'plate' still grow?

Tags: diagnosis, vegetables, planting, bulbs, garlic

I bought a bulb of organic garlic to try and grow.

While separating the cloves, a couple of them broke off that woody root 'plate'.

Will they still grow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they will not. The plate is the only point on a garlic clove where the roots can emerge. Don't plant them, as they may host pests/diseases while decomposing that may affect the other good cloves and spoil the crop.